# VBA Macro to AutoFilter by criteria, copy visible results from one column into an Array, and then AutoFilter a different sheet by that Array

Tags: vba, excel, csv, macros

I'm trying to create a custom report for a technically illiterate client, and I need some help.

So here's what I need to do:

I have two different Workbooks as input files: a Case List (`cases.csv`) and a Revenue Report (`revenue.csv`), which are output from a web service.

The Case List contains Case Filenames (Column K), and Usernames (Column W). All cases and users are listed.

The Revenue Report contains Case Filenames (Column C), and the Revenue Data (Columns G through T), but does not contain associated Usernames (which I need to filter by).

The amount of entries in these lists change all the time, so I need something dynamic.

I basically need to AutoFilter the Revenue Report to only show Cases that are assigned to a specific User.

This is what I have so far for the first part:

```
Set MyRange = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=23, Criteria1:="User1"
Range("K2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Dim arr As Variant
arr = Selection
```

This will AutoFilter the Case List to only show Cases associated with "`User1`", and then copy the visible results of Column K (Case Filenames associated with User1) to an array.

I then wanted to use that Array as the criteria for the second AutoFilter on the second sheet (`revenue.csv`), so that the Revenue Information for only Case Filenames associated with User1 will be visible.

I'm getting stuck on the second part. Preferably, I want the Client to download both reports as CSV files to a specified directory (let's say `C:\test\` as an example).

Then I want them to open this Macro-enabled workbook (let's call it macro.xlsm), which will load the Worksheets of both reports into itself, and then run the code to AutoFilter>Results to Array>AutoFilter again.

Here's my sorry attempt at the loading script.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim directory As String, fileName As String, sheet As Worksheet, total As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
directory = "C:\test\"
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xl??")
Do While fileName <> ""
   Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)
For Each sheet In Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets
    total = Workbooks("macrotest.xlsm").Worksheets.Count
    Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets(sheet.Name).Copy _
    after:=Workbooks("import-sheets.xlsm").Worksheets(total)
Next sheet
Workbooks(fileName).Close
fileName = Dir()
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Basically, I would provide them this macro.xlsm with all the code in it, and all they would have to do is download the two reports into a specific directory, open macro.xlsm, then click a button, and the reports will load in, auto-filter themselves, and the Revenue sheet is filtered by only Cases associated with User1.

HELP!

Comment: HI Scott. just wondering is the "Case Filenames" in both files is unique? If yes, why not trying to use dictionary instead of array and auto filter? Is just my opinion only

Comment: @user2851376 `cases.csv` is an inclusive list of all cases (no duplicate records), and `revenue.csv` would be whichever cases were worked on (also no duplicates). So yeah, Case Filenames would be unique. How can I use a dictionary with an AutoFilter?

Comment: was your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

i have tried to recreate your problem, so the data might be in different cells,

**File 1, cases.csv**

Col A - Case names

Col B - Usernames

**File 2, revenues.csv**

Col A - Case names

Col B - Revenue data

**File 3, Report.xlsm**

Range("A1") = "username"

Col C:D - output (Row 1 is headers)

Run below macro from File 3

```
Sub getRevenue()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    Range("C2:D" & Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).ClearContents

    Dim username As String
    username = Range("A1")

    Dim wbCases As Workbook
    Dim numCases As Integer

    Set wbCases = Workbooks.Open("C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\cases.csv")
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).AutoFilter _
            Field:=2, Criteria1:=username
    Range("A2:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Select
    Selection.Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Range("C2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    numCases = Selection.Rows.Count
    wbCases.Close

    Dim cases() As String
    ReDim cases(1 To numCases) As String
    For i = 1 To numCases
        cases(i) = Selection(i, 1)
    Next i

    Dim wbRev As Workbook
    Set wbRev = Workbooks.Open("C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\Revenue.csv")

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).AutoFilter _
        Field:=1, Criteria1:=cases, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Range("$A$2:$B$" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Select
    Selection.Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Range("C2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    wbRev.Close
End Sub
```

This will generate a list of Cases names and Revenue data for the specified username in Range("A1")

Cheers